# How to make my script not print before a user has entered a string.

Tags: php

Writing a simple script that takes the users string, if it has even characters it counts to 100 with 5's, if odd it count's to 100 with 10's. When loaded in the browser by default it is printing to 100 by 5's. As an empty string 0 qualifies for the first part of my loop. Looking for advice on how to do this properly. Thank you in advance.

```
<form method="post"<br />
PLEASE ENTER A WORD: <input type="text" name="word" value="" /><br />    
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"><br /> 
</form>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['word'])){
$word = $_POST['word'];
} else {
$word ='';
}
?>

<?php

$n = 0;

$word_length = strlen($word);


while ($n < 100){

if($word_length % 2 == 0){ 
$n += 5;
echo $n . "<br />";

} else if($word_length % 2 == 1){
$n += 10;
echo $n . "<br />";

} 

}
?>
```

Comment: Put the `while` inside that `isset` conditional. Also you have HTML issue, `<form method="post"<br />`.

Comment: try if(($word_length % 2) == 0)

Comment: Thank you but both of those did not seem to change anything. I fixed the HTML error though. I tried to put the while inside the isset conditional and it doesn't seem to work at all